# fit columns to maximum cell width with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a two-column tabular layout with CSS flexbox. I want to have have column 1 to be as narrow as possible, tightly fitting all 3 cells in that column. I want column 2 to expand to the remaining width.

I was able to create this: https://codepen.io/ptspts/pen/KKErzeL. The problem with this is that each cell in column 1 has a different width. I want all of them to become as wide as the widest, automatically.

```css
DIV.CONV {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: #888;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
DIV.CONV > DIV.ROW {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
DIV.CONV > DIV.ROW > DIV.C1 {
  display: inline;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #800;
  align-self: start;  /* Vertical alignment. */
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
DIV.CONV > DIV.ROW > DIV.C2 {
  display: block;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: #080;
  align-self: stretch;  /* Vertical alignment. Default. */
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS=CONV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
<DIV CLASS=C1>HI</DIV>
<DIV CLASS=C2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
<DIV CLASS=C1>FOOBAR</DIV>
<DIV CLASS=C2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
<DIV CLASS=C1>LAST</DIV>
<DIV CLASS=C2>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Is this possible at all with CSS flexbox (if yes, how)? If not, is it possible with table, without JavaScript (if yes, how)? If not, is it possible with CSS grid (if yes, how)?

Answer (score 2):

This would be better suited for CSS Grid.

Simply remove all the `rows`, and use a single with `display: grid` and set the template columns to `max-content 1fr`. Essentially the first column will be as wide as the content and the second will be all other remaining space.

```css
DIV.ROW {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

DIV.C1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: #800;
}

DIV.C2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: #080;
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS=CONV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
    <DIV CLASS=C1>HI</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</DIV>

    <DIV CLASS=C1>FOOBAR</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</DIV>

    <DIV CLASS=C1>LAST</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, it's very simple and straightforward with CSS grid. However, I'm still waiting for a definitive answer about flexbox.

Comment: Just to add to @disinfor's answer, if you have no control over the html, you can add `.ROW { display: contents; }` to your CSS to give the same effect.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with flexbox because each div is independent of each other. It'd be possible to make the first column be the min width of the content but then the rows wouldn't align.

Comment: @pts yeah, I don't think you're going to get this with flex, mainly because there is no relationship between any of the `div` elements. Flex wants to make the element as wide as it needs to be unless a property is set to change that. Even setting `max-content` on the `C1` div would only apply to that specific element, not finding every `C1` element, calculating that size and then setting it. Even so, the wrapping of `C2` would still be a problem, since you can't have the width of `C2` be "100% - max-content" of `C1` - I may be wrong

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a table layout

```css
DIV.CONV {
  display: table;
  background-color: #888;
  border-spacing: 6px;
}

DIV.CONV > DIV.ROW {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

DIV.CONV > DIV.ROW > * {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #800;
}

DIV.CONV>DIV.ROW>DIV.C2 {
  background-color: #080;
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS=CONV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
    <DIV CLASS=C1>HI</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
    <DIV CLASS=C1>FOOBAR</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV CLASS=ROW>
    <DIV CLASS=C1>LAST</DIV>
    <DIV CLASS=C2>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```